# Get all mailchimp campaign's details using only one call to MailChimp API v3

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Can I get all mailchimp campaign's details hitting the api only one time instead of hitting the api for each of the campaign ? if yes, how ? only using mailchimp api v3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get multiple campaigns at a time by querying the campaigns collection. You may not be able to retrieve them all at once, though, depending on how many there are.